# How to enable verbose output invoke-command inside inlinescript

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

```
workflow Test-WF {
   param()
        InlineScript {
            $VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
            Write-Verbose "xxx"
            Invoke-Command -cn "localhost" -ScriptBlock {$VerbosePreference='Continue'; Write-Verbose "yyy"}
          }    
}
```

In my example "xxx" is written to output, but "yyy" is not.
How can I cause verbose output inside remotely executed scriptblock inside workflow?

Comment: Running with -PSComputerName works e.g.:InlineScript {
            $VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
            Write-Verbose "yyy"            
        } -PSComputerName "terminal12"but I need invoke-command specifically in real workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by running inlinescript with -PSComputerName parameter and providing machines there. 
It behaves slightly different in some cases than invoke command with cn, but currently it's good enough for me.